# jQuery: using remove(); for a <tr> row by <label> or #id name

Tags: jquery, removeclass

**I need to remove one `<tr>` row in a rendered page using remove(); by targeting the `<label>` name.** *See the markup below.*

There are other `<tr>`rows in this table that need to remain. Is it possible to target one  row in the table by either the text label name "Website" or `label for="url"`?

I.e.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $("target the <tr> by label name Website or "url" ").remove();

  });
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="url">Website</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" class="regular-text code" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not selecting the input which has ID attribute?

```
$('#url').closest('tr').remove();
```

Or if you want to select the label you can use attribute selector:

```
$('label[for="url"]').closest('tr').remove();
```

Or `has` method:

```
$('tr').has('label[for="url"]').remove();
```

<sub>But using ID selector is much efficient.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! All three work, but the first, as you note, is the best. I'm still learning jQuery....

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It will remove only one tr:

```
$('tr').each(function()
{
  if ( $(this).find('th label').html() == 'Website' )
  {
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using attr `for` for you label

```
$('tr').each(function()
{
  if ( $(this).find('label').attr("for") == 'url' )
    $(this).remove();
});
```